# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow excepiton on tweetsharp

Tags: c#, twitter

Hi I have a problem with tweetsharp sdk. I try to read tweets with the code below, sometimes not always I take this exception: "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow". I searched but coludn't find the reason?

```
TweetSharp.TwitterService tester = new TwitterService();

tester.AuthenticateWith(consumerkey, consumersecret, accesstoken, accesstokensecret);

var a = tester.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = "screenname", Count = 100}); //On this line i take the excepiton
```

Comment: I don't think you have posted enough for us to help you.  Example, what does your stack trace look like?  Also, where are performing a math operation that would/could cause the exception type you are seeing?

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to building the source (which can be tricky due to Windows Phone SDK dependencies etc.) you could give this fork a try:
 
https://github.com/timothy-makarov/tweetsharp

It's an unofficial bug fork for TweetSharp wrapped in a NuGet package:
 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp-Unofficial/

We came from TweetSharp v2.3.0, and updating to TweetSharp v2.3.1 did not solve our JSON deserialize problems. Replacing it with the unofficial v.2.3.1.2 package did though.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today. This [issue](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/issues/139) on their github is probably related. There already seems to be a commit to fix this issue: [link](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/commit/c032df4339672de5993de5c9f18ff9730caf1c07), but the last update of nuget is still from Saturday, June 22 2013.

I have no idea if the version on Nuget will ever be updated as version 2.3.1 was the developers last update.

Using the source instead of installing TweetSharp via nuget should fix the problem, but i do not know how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone arriving here with the same issue as user2933990. The following is the correct fix, provided you have added the OAuthTwitterWrapper source code (and compiled) instead of the dll itself.

In the "JsonTypes" directory, modify the following files:

**User.cs**

Original

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Change to

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public long Id { get; set; }
```

**Hashtag.cs**

Original

```
[JsonProperty("indices")]
public List<int> Indices { get; set; }
```

Change to

```
[JsonProperty("indices")]
public List<long> Indices { get; set; }
```